# How do I use the state and data from one page and use it on another

Tags: reactjs, state, multi-page-application

I Would like to use the data searched in component 1 (this is a page which allows you to search for a recipe, it then gives a recipe with name ingredient and instructions) and use that in page 2 (will allow you to see the recipe and then search for the ingredients in a store API)

```
App.js
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <Router>
      <div>
        <Route exact path = '/' component = {Search}/>
        <Route exact path = '/shopping/' component = {Store}/>


      </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}


export default App;


Class Component 1
    class Search extends Component {
      state = {
        drinks: [],
        userInput: "",
        selectedDrink: null,
        recipeName: "",
        recipeInstructions: "",
        recipeIngredients: ""
      };

Class component 2
    class Store extends Component {
      state = {
        recipe: []
      };
```

Comment: You can pass state down as a prop to another component or save the state using some sort of state management middleware like Redux.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the size of your app but there a 2 major option:

1. Moving the state up: You wrap your components into a component (which you likely already have) and set all the state you need into that higher component and pass it down via props. The child components pass the data up via callbacks and update the parent state. This can be useful for small applications and for tightly coupled data.
2. For medium/large applications you want to use a state managment library like [redux](https://redux.js.org/) or [mobx](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx). This gives you performant and independent way to store large amounts of data and easily share it between your different components. This approach has more overhead and a larger learning curve, but is needed for large applciation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So I may not have been 100% clear. Those are my two page components. The first is used to call data from an api. I then want to use that data on the second page which allows you to search a shop for the cost of those things. There is no higher component than those two.

Comment: Ok, so how do you render these components? Do you add both into the Dom independently? You can always just add a component and render the children within that new component. Do you really need a second component just to get data? Does it show anything ( the second component)? If you provide more code, that might clear thinks up ;)

Comment: I am rendering these components in the APP.js File.
APP.js


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <Router>
      <div>
        <Route exact path = '/' component = {Search}/>
        <Route exact path = '/shopping/' component = {Store}/>
      </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}


export default App;

Comment: Which means that your app component wraps the child components. You can give the app component a state.

Comment: Okay. I added more code and explanation to the original comment to make it more clear. Thank you very much, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Every component has a properties. There is a props arrtibute of every react component. Whenever the props or state of a component changes, the render() function runs automatically, and refreshes the component itself.

So you can pass the state of one component to another, using props.
https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

You can also use Redux to manage states globally across components
https://react-redux.js.org/